# GraphQL API Returning 404 Resource Not Found in Consumption Tier APIM

Tags: graphql, azure-api-management

I am trying to add GraphQL API in API Management - Consumption Tier, and it's returning a 404 Resource Not Found error.

```
{
  "statusCode": 404,
  "message": "Resource not found"
}
```

The Same API configuration in Basic Tier and Developer Tier works perfectly fine. Am I missing something? Are GraphQL APIs not supported in consumption tier? Is there any extra configuration required specifically for consumption tier to support graphql APIs?

Please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue and should be fixed by GA. As a workaround use any of the other dedicatd tiers.